# How do I install selenium properly?

Tags: python, selenium

I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'` error while I have `Requirement already satisfied: selenium==3.141.0`. My python version is 3.9.2 and `pip list` and `pip3 list` are identical and both have `selenium 3.141.0`

Comment: Also, can't get bzt to work. Steps I've taken:

 - Uninstall python through cpl 
 - Install python through Windows store
 - pip install bzt

Still get `'bzt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

OS is Windows 11

Comment: maybe you have another Python which doesn't have this module. If you run code `python script.py` then check `python -m pip install selenium` to install in Python which you use  to run code.